# Error #1142 MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, conexão

Hoje em meu sistema me deparei com esta situação. Alimento meus `SELECT` com este código:

`"SELECT p.codigo,p.nome,p.fantasia FROM pessoas p LEFT OUTER JOIN pessoas_define pd ON pd.cod_pessoa = p.codigo WHERE pd.advogado = 'T' AND p.apagado = 0"`

Ou seja tenho a tabela `PESSOA` e na tabela `PESSOAS_DEFINE` defino o tipo. Para a o `SELECT` acima está funcionando 100% porém para o mesmo SELECT trocando somente o campo de `PESSOAS_DEFINE` para "**cliente**" que fica assim:

```
SELECT p.codigo,p.nome,p.fantasia FROM p.pessoas LEFT OUTER JOIN pessoas_define pd ON pd.cod_pessoa = p.codigo WHERE pd.cliente = 'T'
```

Gera o seguinte erro:`"SELECT commnand denied to user 'xxxxxxxxx@ip' for table 'pessoas'".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo este post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956195/mysql-error-1142-select-command-denied-to-user

Eh um erro de permissão na tabela pessoas!

SELECT p.codigo,p.nome,p.fantasia FROM **p.pessoas** LEFT OUTER JOIN pessoas_define pd ON pd.cod_pessoa = p.codigo WHERE pd.cliente = 'T'

Seu SELECT está certo?

Comment: Por isso, o estranho eh que o mesmo: SELECT p.codigo,p.nome,p.fantasia FROM p.pessoas LEFT OUTER JOIN pessoas_define pd ON pd.cod_pessoa = p.codigo WHERE pd.advogado = 'T', funciona ou seja mesma tabela e banco

Comment: Repare o trecho que coloquei em negrito, **FROM p.pessoas**, não seria **FROM pessoas p**? Acho que o erro é este!

Comment: Perfeito era exatamente isso :). As vezes pequenos detalhes nos ferram kkk Obrigado

Comment: Ah... de boa... acontece! :P